# Can't set headers after they are sent in get request

Tags: node.js, express, requestjs

```
router.get('/getpostcode', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.query.suburb);

    var options = {
        url: 'http://apiurl?suburb=' + req.query.suburb + "&state=" + req.query.state ,
        headers: {
            'auth-key': key
        }
    }

    request(options, callback);

    function callback(error, response, body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            info = JSON.parse(body);
            info = info.localities.locality;
            if( Object.prototype.toString.call( info ) == '[object Array]' ){

                for ( var x = 0 ; x < info.length ; x++ ){
                    var locx = info[x].location;
                    var qsuburb = req.query.suburb;

                    if( locx == qsuburb.toUpperCase() ){
                        res.send( { 'postcode': info[x].postcode } );
                    }
                }

            } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call( info ) != '[object Array]') {

                var locx = info.location;
                var qsuburb = req.query.suburb;
                if ( locx == qsuburb.toUpperCase() ){
                    res.send( { 'postcode': info.postcode } );
                }
            }            
        }
    }
});
```

So, I am trying to request data from an API and then based on that data, I am then sending some data back. My code is as above.

Unfortunately, in the callback function, when I am running a loop to find a specific element that I will then send back to the client, when sending that element to client, I am getting the error as shown in the title.

This does not occur when there is no loop and I simply send one element of the data back.

Any ideas on what this could be?

Comment: Once the response is sent for a particular request, again another response cannot be sent. So, try to accumulate the response and send it at once

Comment: I agree with @ChandanKumarV you need to keep the data you want to send maybe in an array and then send all at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending response more than one for one request, write res.send or JSON outside the loop.

```
for (var x = 0; x < info.length; x++) {
    var locx = info[x].location;
    var qsuburb = req.query.suburb;
    var postcodes = [];
    if (locx == qsuburb.toUpperCase()) {
        postcodes.push({
            'postcode': info[x].postcode
        });
    }
    res.json(postcodes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reaching the `res.send` function call at least twice in your flow and this is not allowed. That function must be called once to send the response to the client.

Comment: Ok. You mean in the loop, correct? I was under the assumption that res.send() would result in the program basically terminating at that stage, which I guess is clearly not true.

Comment: exactly, res.send is not terminal, it simply sends back a response to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, As [@Rahul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8879527/rahul-sharma) said, It is not allowed to send response more than one time for the same request - You must be getting same post code, so you either need to store your postcode in a variable and send it after loop overs or you can use a `break`. Though it is not advisable to use a break in complex loops in the pretty simple loop you can leverage its usage.

```
for (var x = 0; x < info.length; x++) {
    var locx = info[x].location;
    var qsuburb = req.query.suburb;

    if (locx == qsuburb.toUpperCase()) {
        res.send({
            'postcode': info[x].postcode
        });
        break;
    }
}
```

Or as following:

```
for (var x = 0; x < info.length; x++) {
    var locx = info[x].location;
    var qsuburb = req.query.suburb;
    vat postcode = = null;
    if (locx == qsuburb.toUpperCase()) {
        postcode = info[x].postcode
    }
}
res.send({
    postcode
});
```